# Issue styling a d3 js tree chart in a DIV

Tags: css, d3.js

I have a tree chart which I would like to put into a div tag, so that I can hide the chart and control its positioning easily.

But this doesnt work when I try to fit d3 chart into a different div.

Tried this way -

```
<div class="overviewMain" id="overviewMain">
    <div class="overviewHeader"><span>Overview</span></div>
    <div class="treediv" style="margin-top:60px;">
        <div id="tree"></div>    /*  --> D3 Tree chart */
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JnNwu/974/

what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are appending your SVG to `body` instead of the `div`.

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
```

Change this to append to the desired div `#tree`

```
var svg = d3.select("#tree").append("svg")
```

See the working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JnNwu/975/).

Comment: Thanks a lot altocumulus!